# Why is the Minkowski functional well defined

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In my notes the Minkowski functional, given an open neighbourhood of $0$ $C$, is defined on a topological vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) as
$$ \mu_C(v)=\inf\{ t>0\ |\ v\in tC\} $$
Then it is proved that if $C$ is absolutely convex and bounded then it defines a norm on the vector space. However I can't see why this necessarily exists, i.e. why there must exist such a $t$ satisfying $v\in tC$.

Comment: The continuity of the scalar multiplication $\mathbb K\times X\to X$ implies that also $\mathbb K\to X$, $r\mapsto rv$ is continuous at $r=0$ for fixed $v$. Hence there is $\delta>0$ such that $|r|<\delta$ implies $rv\in C$ and hence $v\in tC$ for all $|t|>1/\delta$. BTW, in general, $\mu_C$ is only a *seminorm* and not a proper norm.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0\in C^\circ$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $B(0,\delta) \subseteq C$. Now notice that if $v' = \frac{\delta}{2\lVert v \rVert}v$ then $\lVert v' \rVert = \frac{\delta}{2}$ so $v' \in C$. From that we deduce that $v \in \frac{2\lVert v \rVert}{\delta}C$  so the set $\{t>0\mid v \in tC\}$ is non empty and the Minkowski functional is well defined.

The above is valid when $v\neq 0$. The case of $v=0$ is trivial.

**EDIT:** Without the assumption that the space is normed what you have to show is that every neighborhood of $0$ is absorbing. You can see that by considering the sequence $v_n = \frac{1}{n}v$. This sequence converges to $0$ so every neighborhood of $0$ contains some (many) $v_n$.

Comment: But doesn't that proof rely on there already being a norm defined on the topological vector space? The Minkowski functional is being used to prove that given there is an absolutely convex, bounded open neighbourhood of 0 then the topological vector space is normable, so I guess I'm asking for a proof without the use of a norm already defined on the space.

Comment: @userbignumber See my edited answer.